# A continuous real-valued function $f$ on $E$ then for any $a \in R \{p \in E : f(p)>a\}$ and $\{p \in E : f(p)<a\}$ are open subsets of $E$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on the metric space $E$ then for any $a \in R$ $ \{p \in E : f(p)>a\}$ and $\{p \in E : f(p)<a\}$ are open subsets of $E$.

What are some applications of this statement? This is a corollary of a proposition, $f:E \rightarrow E'$ is continuous if and only if, for every open subset $U$ of $E'$, the inverse image of $U$ is an open subset of $E$.

One application is $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is closed.